# Problem with beamer in persian/farsi

Tags: beamer, languages, persian

I tried to create slides with `beamer` and the `babel` package with Farsi option `\usepackage[farsi]{babel}`. When I run it, I have some errors.

I use this code:

```
\documentclass[‎ucs‎]{beamer}‎‎
‎\usetheme{Aalborg}‎
  \usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}‎
‎\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}‎
% ‎Or whatever‎. ‎Note that the encoding and the font should match‎. ‎If T1‎
% ‎does not look nice‎, ‎try deleting the line with the fontenc‎.
‎\usepackage{helvet}‎
‎\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structurebold}‎
‎\setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size=\normalsize,series=\bfseries}‎
‎\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}‎

% ‎Standard packages‎

‎\usepackage[‎fars‎i]{babel}‎
‎\usepackage{fontspec}‎
‎\usepackage{amsmath}‎
‎\setmainfont[Script=Arabic,Numbers=Arabic]{XB Zar}‎‎\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Numbers=Arabic]{XB Zar}‎
 ‎Setup TikZ‎

‎\usepackage{tikz}‎
‎\usetikzlibrary{arrows}‎
‎\tikzstyle{block}=[draw opacity=0.7,line width=1.4cm]‎
‎‎
% ‎colored hyperlinks‎
‎\newcommand{\chref}[2]{%‎
  ‎\href{#1}{{\usebeamercolor[bg]{Aalborg}#2}}%‎
}

‎\begin{document}‎
% ‎the titlepage‎
%‎{\aauwavesbg‎
‎%\begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering] % the plain option removes the sidebar and header from the title page‎
  ‎%\titlepage‎
‎%\end{frame}}‎‎
\begin{frame}
‏سلام
\end{frame}
‎\end{document}‎‎
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: What error do you exactly get and how do you compile the code? My guess is you either are missing `Aalborg` theme, or compiling it with the wrong command. But first you should provide some more details about your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is code that works in XeLaTeX, may be able to get you running.  Add your tweaks (packages, preferences, etc) to it VERY carefully, line by line, compiling each time to check if you've introduced errors.  Remember, all Persian text must live inside `{\F }` (which means my solution may not be ideal).  If you do not have "Geeza Pro" on your system, use the title of another Farsi typeface.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{beamer}

% PACKAGES

\usepackage{fontspec}

% BEGIN

\begin{document}

% RUNTIME TWEAKS

\newfontfamily{\F}{Geeza Pro} % Farsi

% THE MEAT

\begin{frame}
Persian: {\F سلام}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to mix lines which are non-XeLaTeX-ish with ones that are:

- You use `\usepackage{helvet}` and old fashioned encoding definition. Try using Helvetica through font definition in `fontspec`. You might want to switch to [a free / open-source font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_Unicode_typefaces) as well…
- You use [`babel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel) instead of [`polyglossia`](http://ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia).

I don't know what error messages *you* get. I hope this will help you in solving this problem, which is unfortunately not well-defined as worded.