# Problem with preparing presentation slides in persian/arabic language

Tags: beamer, languages

I am trying to make my thesis presentation slides in persian language using beamer and xelatex or bidi; I am using texlive but when I run the following code without any error, the persian fonts do not appear in the final PDF file. What should I do?

I have seen that the arabic fonts also work for persian language files, so if you can make these slides work for arabic language, it will be useful. Please note that I am very basic user, so please write your answers so basic that I understand them.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Yas}

\usetheme{Rochester}
\usecolortheme{wolverine}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\large}

\title{{\footnotesize \bf عنوان}}
\author[نویسنده]{نویسنده}
\institute[دانشگاه]{دانشگاه}

\AtBeginSection[]  % The commands within the following {} will be executed at the start of each section.
{
\begin{frame} % Within each "frame" there will be one or more "slides."  
\frametitle{Presentation Outline} % This is the title of the outline.
\tableofcontents[currentsection]  % This will display the table of contents and highlight the current section.
\end{frame}
} % Do not include the preceding set of commands if you prefer not to have a recurring outline displayed during your presentation.

\begin{document}

\begin{frame} 
\titlepage
\end{frame}

            \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{اولین اسلاید}
    %Content goes here
  \end{frame}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{دومین اسلاید}
    \framesubtitle{دومین مطلب}
    %More content goes here
  \end{frame}
% etc
\end{document}
```

Comment: You must write your source file in utf8 encoding  to use with XeLaTeX

Answer (score 4):

you would like presentation like this

[image]

- First you must define Sans Serif Font ( for headings ) with `\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[]{Name of font}`
- Second To put frametitles on the right you can use `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][right]`
- you must put your Persian  text inside `\textarabic{text}` or with environment `\begin{Arabic}   \end{Arabic}`  (for long text)
- Text inside frame should be placed inside `minipage` env To avoid wrong alignment

  ```
  \documentclass{beamer}
  \usepackage{setspace}

  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setmainlanguage{english}
  \setotherlanguage{arabic}

  \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Amiri}% I have not Yas font
  \newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Amiri}

  \usetheme{Rochester}
  \usecolortheme{wolverine}

  \beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

  \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
  \setbeamerfont{page number in head/foot}{size=\large}

  \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][right]% align the frametitle to the right


  \title{{\footnotesize \bf \textarabic{عنوان}}}
  \author[\textarabic{نویسنده}]{\textarabic{نویسنده}}
  \institute[\textarabic{دانشگاه}]{\textarabic{دانشگاه}}

  \AtBeginSection[]  % The commands within the following {} will be executed at the  start of each section.
  {
  \begin{frame} % Within each "frame" there will be one or more "slides."  
  \frametitle{Presentation Outline} % This is the title of the outline.
  \tableofcontents[currentsection]  % This will display the table of contents and highlight the current section.
  \end{frame}
   } % Do not include the preceding set of commands if you prefer not to have a    recurring outline displayed during your presentation.

  \begin{document}

  \begin{frame} 
  \titlepage
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{\textarabic{اولین اسلاید}}
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    %Content goes here
  \end{minipage}
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{\textarabic{دومین اسلاید}}
  \framesubtitle{\textarabic{دومین مطلب}}
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    %More content goes here
  \end{minipage}
  \end{frame}

  \end{document}
  ```

Comment: What to do with numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Please see this 
[answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152491/problem-with-beamer-in-persian-farsi) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197575/the-best-way-to-write-arabic-in-beamer).
I apply the latter in your document on `\author` as

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[utf]{arabxetex}%this line added
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
%\setotherlanguage{arabic}%this line removed
.
.
.
\author[\textarab{نویسنده}]{\textarab{نویسنده}}
```

and "نویسنده" appears in my output. of course this produces some errors but works!!!

Comment: A full example, best with a screen shot would improve this answer