# textbf doesn't work in persian beamer

Tags: beamer, xetex, text

Could anyone help me to solve the problem? What should I use instead of textbf?

```
\documentclass{beamer}‎‎‎
‎\usetheme{Warsaw}‎
\usepackage{graphicx}‎‎
\usefonttheme{serif}‎
\usepackage{ptext}‎
\usepackage{xepersian}‎
\settextfont{Yas}‎‎

\begin{document}‎
\section{‏پاسخ‎\hfill}‎
\subsection{‌تاریخ\hfill}
\subsection{آز\hfill}
\begin{frame}‎
\textbf{سلام}
دوستان عزیز
\end{frame}‎
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you try to compile your file using `xelatex`? Look at the link: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197575/the-best-way-to-write-arabic-in-beamer or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152491/problem-with-beamer-in-persian-farsi. Peraphs you can resolve the question.

Comment: I used biditex and quick build @Sebastiano

Comment: They didn't help. @Sebastiano

Comment: Dear Sara I use Papeeria (https://papeeria.com) or Overleaf (https://www.overleaf.com/). I can to compile only with `pdflatex`, `xelatex` or `lualatex`. Sorry. I can't see your persian characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that you don't have the bold version of the font installed.

There is a free font called *XB Yas*, available on https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/xb-yas (license: GPL), which includes four fonts: regular, bold, italic, and bold italic.

After installing the fonts on your computer (or uploading them to ShareLaTeX), and changing the font name in `\settextfont{XB Yas}`, your example runs fine on my computer (I've repeated the *dear friends* phrase bold and regular, for comparison).

[image]